# Cannot call 'operator >' with 'expr2'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: float

Tags: operators, pine-script

I want to create an alert for break out level. I want to get alert on 5 min chart by analysing data on daily time frame.

I am getting above subject error and not able to solve.

If I use "valuewhen" then error is not coming but my script is not producing any result.

```
//@version=4

study("Breakout", overlay = true)

var string day = "D"
vol = security(syminfo.ticker,day, volume[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on) 
h1 = security(syminfo.ticker,day, high[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
l1 = security(syminfo.ticker,day, low[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
h2 = security(syminfo.ticker,day, high[2], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
l2 = security(syminfo.ticker,day, low[2], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)

breakout = vol > 500000 and h1 - l1 < h2 - l2 and close > h1

bo =  close > breakout

plotshape(series=bo, title="Long", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text="Buy")
```

Comment: when I used "valuewhen" it gives signal on every 5 min bar candle. but I want to get signal on only one candle which has completed the last condition "bo =  close > breakout"

Answer (score 0):

`breakout` is a boolean, `close` represents an asset's specific candle's price, hence when you try to compare `close` with `breakout` in the `bo` variable the compilation error occurs.

Either you declare a value to the `breakout` variable and then compare it with the asset's price, previous high value for example:

```
breakout = (vol > 500000) and (h1 - l1 < h2 - l2) and (close > h1) ? high[1] : na    
bo =  close > breakout
```

or use the breakout boolean as a series for your signal and plotshape() function:

```
breakout = (vol > 500000) and (h1 - l1 < h2 - l2) and (close > h1) 
plotshape(series=breakout, title="Long", style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), text="Buy")
```